Drag and Drop Not Working in AngularJS Project with angular-native-dragdrop After Chrome Update
I have an old AngularJS project where I use the angular-native-dragdrop package for drag-and-drop functionality. After updating Chrome to version 125.0.6422.61, the drag-and-drop feature has stopped working correctly.
When I try to change the order of items in my list using drag and drop, the changes are not applied to json.
Here are some details about my setup:
AngularJS version: 1.8.2
angular-native-dragdrop version: 1.1.2
Chrome version: 125.0.6422.61
Has anyone experienced a similar issue or knows a workaround for this problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I have drag&drop problems too after update to Chrome 125 (which 124 does not have), though not with an Angular project. Seems like 'draggable' is now on by default or something. It does not happen on Firefox, but Edge/Chrome/Chromium all behave the same way after update.
With 125 e.g.  anchors seem draggable, which they were not before.
Only with something like this I can get it to work as before:
 document.addEventListener('dragstart', function() {
    if $(event.target).closest("[draggable='true']").length<=0) {
       event.preventDefault();
    }
 });

but I'm still investigating and not sure if that covers everything.
